# Получение значения параметра

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Вручную вызываю в коде программы обработчик события dropdownlist и передаю туда параметры. В качестве sender передаю массив из двух элементов типа object.

```
object[] mas = new object[2];
mas[0] = "Home.aspx";
mas[1] = ddlSelUnit.SelectedItem.Text;
ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged(mas, null);
```

Как мне в обработчике событий взять эти параметры?
Sender[0], так нельзя. А как по другому обратиться к каждому из элементов массива я что то не могу понять.

Comment: Очень странный подход. Но должно работать так: `((object[])sender)[0]` или `var mas = (object[])sender; mas[0]...`

Comment: Почему не использовать просто метод и передавать туда нормальные типизированные параметры? sender - это так-то тот кто инициирует событие по идее...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы решаете проблему не в том направлении. Обработчик события - это не какая-то магия, это просто метод с определенной сигнатурой, приспособленный для реакции на события. Вы же не реагируете на событие, вы просто вызываете свой код.

Вызов `ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged` тут не нужен -  в `ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged` должен быть написан код, реагирующий на событие "смена индекса выделенного элемента в `ddlSelAggregate`. И в параметрах он должен ожидать вызвавший эту смену дропдаун (`ddlSelAggregate`) и пустые event args. Если он начнет ожидать вторым параметром какой-то кастомный объект - ваш код некрасиво упадет с `InvalidCastException` при вызове реального события `SelectedIndexChanged` у реального контрола `ddlSelAggregate` - т.к. стандартный дропдаун вообще не в курсе, что вы ожидаете вторым параметром какой-то `MyArgs`. По сути, в соседних ответах вам советуют решение, которое

- Или упадет при вызове события `SelectedIndexChanged` у `ddlSelAggregate` (если вы на него подписаны)
- Или решает проблему вызова вашего же кода из вашего же кода через неудобную сигнатуру метода и абсолютно ненужный каст (если ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged не подписан на `SelectedIndexChanged` у `ddlSelAggregate`, а называется так просто так, и сигнатура у него просто так задана в виде обработчика события)

Если же `ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged` больше не вызвается в качестве реакции на `SelectedIndexChanged` у `ddlSelAggregate` - то почему у него до сих пор такое имя и сигнатура? Это же ваш код, он следует вашим правилам - поменяйте сигнатуру на удобную вам. И имя вместе с ней, чтобы оно не вводило в заблуждение.

---

Если вам нужно передать в кусок своего кода два параметра - вынесите этот кусок кода в отдельный метод, и передавайте в него значения:

```
void ChangeSelectedUnit(string someUrl, string unit)
{
    // тут ваш код, работающий с "home.aspx" и unit
}
```

Вызов:

```
ChangeSelectedUnit(someUrl, unit);
```

Если этот же код нужно вызывать на смене `ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged` - в теле `ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged` соберите нужные вам параметры из контролов, и вызовите тот же `ChangeSelectedUnit`:

```
protected void ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeSelectedUnit(
               // тут someUrl и unit, которые сейчас у вас используются в коде ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged 
               // при натуральном (не "ручном") вызове
                      );
}
```

Comment: `ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged` как раз является обработчиком событий и вызывается в ответ на смену индекса dropdownlist просто мне нужно было сделать так. Что смены индекса не было, а я всё равно вызываю этот обработчик. Как бы это сказать. "Искусственно" моделирую вызов обработчика.

Comment: @Андрей ну тогда два соседних ответа радостно упадут при "натуральном" вызове обработчика. Я уже написал выше - обработчик - это *ваш* код, который вызывается в ответ на внешнее событие (смену индекса). Если вам нужно выполнить какой-то код и в ответ на смену индекса (натуральную) и в случае " смены индекса не было"  - вынесите его в отдельный метод (ChangeSelectedUnit), и вызывайте этот метод и в обработчике ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged, и вручную, там где вам это нужно

Comment: @Андрей т.е. вы решаете проблему вида "нужно поменять код так, чтобы вручную вызвать ту часть кода, которая сейчас вызывается при смене индекса". это эквивалентно  "есть код, который нужно вызывать и вручную, и при смене индекса". извлекаете этот код в метод, вызываете в двух местах.

Comment: @PashaPash по поводу ```радостно упадут при "натуральном" вызове обработчика``` - это дело поправимое. Хотя вызов обработчика вручную это да, нехорошо :)

Comment: @PashaPash там условия построены так, что при моём вызове обработчика в ручную не когда не сработает натуральный вызов обработчика. Суть задачи в том что я правил баг который моделируется путём запуска сайта, а потом копировании ссылки и работы с одним, по сути сайтом, но с двух копий. И вот для такого случая я и вызываю обработчик в ручную.

Comment: @Андрей вопрос не в том, как у вас построены условия, и сколько раз вызовется обработчик :) Вопрос в том, что вам нужно не "вызвать обработчик вручную", а выполнить код, который у вас сейчас в этом обработчике написан. Если вам нужно выполнить код с передачей в него параметров - вынесите его в отдельный метод с удобными для вас типами параметров и вызовите этот метод.

Comment: @Андрей у меня сложилось впечатление, что вы не понимаете что такое обработчик. Обработчик события - это просто метод с определенными типами параметров. Т.е. когда вы говорите "я вызываю обработчик вручную" на самом деле вы "вызываете метод ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged". Без "вручную". И ваш вопрос сводится к "как передать два параметра в метод" - ответ на него - поменяйте определение метода так, чтобы он принимал нужные вам параметры, и назовите его соответственно. Если этот метод нужно будет вызывать при обработке события - вызывайте этот метод из обработчика события.

Comment: @PashaPash ясно, теперь я понял вас.

Answer (score 5):

Параметры желательно передавать как аргументы, а не как отправителя события. 
Для этого:

Делаем класс для аргументов

```
public class MyArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object param1 { get; set;}
    public object param2 { get; set;}
    /* тут всё, что хотите передать */
}
```

Отправляем аргументы как аргументы

```
ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged(this, new MyArgs() {param1=/**/, param2=/**/});
```

И работаем с ними так

```
private void ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var myObject = e as MyArgs; // проверка что тип параметра именно тот, что вы ожидаете 
    if (myObject!=null)
    {       
        var param1 = myObject.param1;
        var param2 = myObject.param2;
    }
}
```

UPD. Тут рассматривается только способ передачи аргументов в обработчик события. Вопросы зачем это вообще делать не рассматриваются, так как есть множество вариантов как решить ту или иную проблему. Подробнее в ответе от @PashaPash

Answer (score 2):

Создайте новый класс с нужными вам полями:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
}
```

Создайте экземпляр класса, внесите в его поля нужные значения и передайте в обработчик:

```
    var mas = new MyType()
    {
        param1 = "Home.aspx",
        param2 = ddlSelUnit.SelectedItem.Text
    };
    ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged(mas, null);
```

В обработчике приведите Object к вашему типу, тогда вы сможете получить значения полей объекта:

```
    private void ddlSelAggregate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var myObject = (MyType)sender;
        var param1 = myObject.param1;
        var param2 = myObject.param2;
        ....
    }
```

Можно еще привести объект к массиву объектов, но это плохой подход.

Лучше передать свой объект в обработчик как аргумент, как это сделать описано в соседнем ответе.

Comment: И следующий кто прицепит сюда обработчик OnChange будет материть того кто этот "механизм" придумал. Концепция Sender подразумевает отправитель (кнопка, меню и т д), а не массив или сторонний обьект. Хотя... всё что не запрещено - разрешено)